# How to understand a Hilbert Space of functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Here are some of my understandings of Hilbert Space of functions, I am not sure.
L2 space is a Hilbert Space of all square integrable functions. It's easy to understand. And the dimension of this space is infinity; It maps a function f: R -> R into a point in L2 space.

Then what about a discrete function f: R^2->R, whose domain contains only (0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1). And its range is some real value. Then this kind of function's space is 4 dimension, am I right?

Then what about a function f: R^2->R, whose domain is two dimension real value, and range is one dimension real value. Then this function space's dimension is infinity, but different than  the dimension of L2. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

For any (finite) dimension $d$, $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is a separable, infinite dimensional,  Hilbert space.

Comment: Then what about the discrete function whose domain some finite points?

Comment: These are all finite dimensional, with dimension equal to the number of points.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really need someone professional to confirm my idea.